# How can I create dynamic table in Thymeleaf..?

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and trying to create a dynamic table on Themeleaf template.

How can I do it..??

I have been googling by I didn't got any proper answer. The issue is I cannot iterate List< Map< String,Object >>. I can have any number of columns and columns name could be any thing.

```
<tr class="headings">
 <th class="column-title">ID</th>
 <th class="column-title">Name</th>
 <th class="column-title">Salary</th>
 <th class="column-title">Status</th>  
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="even pointer" th:each="row:${rows}" id = "tablerow">
 <td class=" " th:text="${row.getId()}">Id</td>
 <td class=" " th:text="${row.getName()}">Name</td>
 <td class=" " th:utext="${row.getSalary()}">Salary</td>
 <td class=" " th:text="${row.getStatus()}">Active</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to set values dynamically since if query of result will keep changing . right now column name are hard coded and value are also getting by **row.getId** what if there is no Id, it could be anything in rows what shall I use than..? example row.<>.
rows is obtained as List< Map< String, Object>>.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can iterative over a `Map` just as easily as you can a `List`.  The simplest form of this would be:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="even pointer" th:each="row: ${rows}" id="tablerow">
        <td th:each="field: ${row}" th:text="${field.value}" />
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, since `Maps` don't have a specific ordering (unless you're using something like a `TreeMap`), the way I would do it would be something like this (complete example should match your example table):

Controller

```
List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("ID", "Name", "Salary", "Status");
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(Map.of("ID", "1", "Name", "Jim", "Salary", "50000", "Status", "active"));
rows.add(Map.of("ID", "2", "Name", "Sally", "Salary", "50000", "Status", "inactive"));
```

Template

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th th:each="header: ${headers}" class="column-title" th:text="${header}" />
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="even pointer" th:each="row: ${rows}" id="tablerow">
            <td th:each="header: ${headers}" th:text="${row.get(header)}" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which will produce:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th class="column-title" >ID</th>
            <th class="column-title" >Name</th>
            <th class="column-title" >Salary</th>
            <th class="column-title" >Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="even pointer" id="tablerow">
            <td >1</td>
            <td >Jim</td>
            <td >50000</td>
            <td >active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even pointer" id="tablerow">
            <td >2</td>
            <td >Sally</td>
            <td >50000</td>
            <td >inactive</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```